# Overwriting css settings for different screen sizes

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to set different css settings for a certain class for smaller devices than for bigger screens, but my css code is not working as I want it to. I mainly use Bootstrap in my project, but I am also adding some of my own css. For "normal" sized screens I am using this css code:

```
div.middleDiv{
max-height: 100%;
overflow: scroll;
}
```

And for smaller devices I want to use the following settings for `middleDiv` class:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
   div.middleDiv{
   overflow: visible;
   max-height: none;
   }
}
```

My idea is to put scrollbar only on the desired div in case there is an overflow on normal devices (for example computer), but I like the default settings for smaller devices so I want to keep the default settings for those. It seems that I cannot "overwrite" the settings I have for default devices. Can anyone please help me? I will also include screenshots of what I want below. Thank you.

[image: First screenshot]

[image: Second screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access scrollbar property by accessing: `::-webkit-scrollbar` .Try below css.

CSS :

```
::-webkit-scrollbar { 
    display: none; 
}
```

Comment: This does hide the scrollbar, but it doesn't actually disable it... It works as if it is still there. Do you have any other idea how to fix this maybe?

Comment: Ok just found the solution... I just had to put the css code that worked only in case of proper screen size on bottom of my css file. Thank you again :)

Comment: I think this solution doesn't work for all browsers.
This works only in webkit browsers.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be the 100% height of your DIV. You could try like this:

```
div.middleDiv{
  max-height: calc(100vh - 20px);
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Try here:
https://plnkr.co/edit/uNqhrweIBJaMsLDRQ9PX